# Why is my RTC repository workspace not loaded?

Tags: source-control

On Friday, my Rational Team Concert repository workspace was loaded in my local RTC Eclipse environment with folders on my hard drive

Today, for some reason RTC does not consider it "loaded". It is giving me a "Accepting incoming changes into a disconnected component will not load them into the sandbox. Do you want to continue?" warning when I try to accept the incoming changes, and it's not showing any outgoing changes when I refresh the filesystem.

The tetris piece representing the source control component is outlined blue (not loaded) rather than filled in blue (loaded).

Why isn't my checkout considered "loaded" anymore? How do I make it consider the workspace loaded without overwriting my local changes?

In the past, I've dealt with this situation by:

1. Making a copy of my checkout folders
2. Reloading them from source control
3. Overwriting the the load wiht my backup copy

This is a time-intensive and error-prone procedure. Is there any way to make RTC just recognize the same workspace that it had before?

Tag suggestions: rtc rational-team-concert jazz

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've noticed this happen when RTC has locked itself out of it's own workspace files. Instead of reloading the entire workspace, you can try forcing a load of a single component.

1) Under "My Repository Workspaces" find your workspace, and find a small component. Right-click and Load As

2) In the Load Repository Folder dialog, it may not show any items in Sandbox (or, it may show your root source folder). If you can't find the target workspace, use Create and select the existing folder on disk, where your source was previously. Also use the same directory name for the component.

3) Hit Finish. If you had loaded this component previously, it will tell you that content is already at the destination. That's fine, overwrite it (if you had changes in there you want to keep, copy them out first).

4) After it loads the component, it should refresh its own view of the workspace, and "remember" that you had the other components loaded.

I have found this to be faster than reloading the entire workspace, since you can pick a component that will load very quickly. But you will probably have to repeat this for each workspace in order to refresh them all.

Answer (score 5):

I was looking for answer to this for long time. From my purely personal opinion - I've never had do deal with so much crap like when using this tool. I can hardly believe somebody wants to get money from selling this when there are other alternatives which will at least DO the task (I'm not even targeting "do better" thing). Now - when the rage has flown through me already...

I do lots of syncing between our local git repository and client's RTC. And situation like above happens mostly when using command line **lscm** tool while not having eclipse opened. Seems like this part (ie. lack of eclipse) is the "disconnection" thing. Solution I've found today is:

- close everything
- restart your computer
- open RTC's Eclipse FIRST

Comment: Absolutely agree about this "never had to deal with so much crap" part!

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question now, but for posterity's sake, I just ran into this issue and I found a different solution:

1. Close Eclipse. (Wait for it to completely shut down.)
2. Open Task Manager and check whether you still have an Eclipse process running.
3. If you find one, kill it, then open Eclipse again.

This solved it for me. It seems that once in a while, if Eclipse doesn't shut down properly, it keeps ownership of a few files in your workspace's `.jazz5/` directory that prevent the RTC plugin from working properly.

Answer (score 0):

I was primarily getting this window when clicking the (second from the right) button in the top right of the Pending Changes window that says "Accept All Incoming Baselines And Change Set" when you hover over it.  Instead, if you start by accepting Incoming changes individually by project, you may sill see this window, but then you will be aware of (one of) the specific project(s) that is causing the problem. If you see this pop up while accepting individual project changes, then (as @Deniz mentioned in above answer) in Project Explorer right click on the misbehaving project and click Load As.
(Now, citing @Deniz's answer) In the Load Repository Folder dialog, it may not show any items in Sandbox (or, it may show your root source folder). If you can't find the target workspace, use Create and select the existing folder on disk, where your source was previously. Also use the same directory name for the componeni
Now you loaded the misbehaving project, and should be able to accept its Incoming changes in Pending Changes window.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).